# python Ranking on rows having same value is giving random ranking not as ascending = False

Tags: python, duplicates, rank, ranking-functions, unique-values

Here is df, I want to Rank on value on group "Id" , ranking  within class

df['Rank']=df.groupby(["Id"])[' value'].rank(ascending=0)

[Sample df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwC5T.png)

Expected Result

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QD9J.png)

Result what I get from above code
[Result what I get from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30A33.png)

Above code works well if value are unique
Example
df

[Example df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c48EW.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDEcu.png)

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Can you `print(df.sample(5).to_dict("list"))` and add it to your post with the matching expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use a dense method on [`pandas.Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) :

```
df['Rank']= df.groupby('ID')['Value'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   ID Class  Value  Rank
0  US     A     10     1
1  US     B     10     1
2  US     C      2     2
3  US     D      2     2
```

Input used :

```
   ID Class  Value
0  US     A     10
1  US     B     10
2  US     C      2
3  US     D      2
```